# Singleton plugin activation; create database

Tags: php, plugin-development

within my singleton I have these functions

```
class plugin {

  private static $_instance;

  private function __construct() {
    //does all add_actions & filters
    $this->_register_hooks();
  }


  public static function getInstance() {
    if ( ! ( self::$_instance instanceof self ) ) {
        self::$_instance = new self();
    }

    return self::$_instance;
  }

  static function create_order_table() {
    global $wpdb;

      $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "order";
      $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

      $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        name varchar(200) NOT NULL,
        description int(11) NOT NULL,
        alt_text int(11) NOT NULL,
        sort_order int(11) NOT NULL,
        time datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
      ) $charset_collate;";

      require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
      dbDelta( $sql );

      add_option( 'db_version', DB_VERSION );
  }


 /**
  * ATIVATION
  * on activation the plugin creates databases
  * @access public
  * @since 1.0
  */
  public function activate() {

        // DATABASE
        //creates table
    register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( &$this, 'create_order_table' ) );
  }
}
```

and after I init my class I do this:

```
global $plugin;

if ( ! $plugin ) {
  $plugin = plugin::getInstance();
  $plugin->activate();
}
```

but nothing happens, why isn't it taking?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It's perfectly working for me. Would you please give the full class code?

Comment: sure. but it's kinda long so i'll just give you some of the methods.

Comment: I updated the question with the class

Answer (score 0):

There is an error here. You've not declared `_register_hooks()` method. 
And I instantiated the class like below-

```
global $p;

if(empty($p)){
    $p = plugin::getInstance();
    $p->activate();
}
```

And it worked. For your case that has not worked cause WordPress uses a variable with name `$plugin` in its life cycle. And your code checks it's empty or not. Obviously it's not gonna be empty. So your `$plugin = plugin::getInstance();` never executed. For using this singleton pattern your better declare the variable `$plugin` with a different name. Like I declared it as `$p` here. Better you prefix with something unique. Hope that suggestion helps you.

Comment: I don't understand how it works for you?

Comment: I have exactly that changed the name and everything and it still won't create a database I look in the logs and nothing shows up. Is there another way to see bugs?

Comment: when I put 
```register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( $myy_plugin, 'create_order_table' ) );```

inside the if statement it works but not when I call it using the activate() function...